# Badge vs. Permit/Pass

Tags: word-request

Would you still call a ribbon-hung badge a badge if it were to be worn to show you have permission to leave a place, enter one or use a facility? Would the place make any difference if it was a factory, company/organization or school?

I think a badge is generic enough to use it in various situations, other than as an ID or to show you are a visitor, and whether hung around the neck, pinned or sewn to clothes.

Someone suggested I call it a pass or a permit. What do you think?

Comment: No everyone cares to make that distinction. https://www.uline.com/BL_820/Badge-Holders

Comment: *Permit* and *pass* have a more general usage than *badge*, and often refer to permission to take a specific action, for example a "parking *permit*". Adding definitions to your question might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

"Badge" is a generic term for a device that shows *authorization* or *authority*.  You would use your *badge* to get into a restricted area because your job requires that you be there.

A "permit" or a  "pass" connotes *permission* to enter an area, but the feeling is that you have been *authorized* by someone else, usually only temporarily, because your job doesn't require you to be there all the time, or you are only required for a specified period of time.

For example,

> I got a parking permit (or parking pass) that allows me to park in the lot near my office, but I need a badge to get into the office itself.
>
> If you want to get onto the military base you need to be issued a pass by the guard, unless you are on active duty, in which case you just show them your ID badge at the gate.